# Difference between using androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen and PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-xml, android-preferences, androidx

My app targets `API 28` and has a minimum `API 15`. As support library, I'm using `AndroidX`.
I have a preference fragment hosted by an activity, like this:

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

    }
}
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

And here is the XML layout used by `SettingsFragment.java`

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="pref_switch"
        android:title="@string/switch" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

As the root of the preference hierarchy, should I use `PreferenceScreen` or `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen` for the layout to actually be backward compatible (using AndroidX)? What is the difference between the two? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/):

> AndroidX is the open-source project that the Android team uses to
>   develop, test, package, version and release libraries within [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack).
>
> AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android [Support
>   Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index). Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the
>   Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android
>   releases. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing
>   feature parity and new libraries. In addition AndroidX includes the
>   following features:
>
> - All packages in AndroidX live in a consistent namespace starting with the string `androidx`. The Support Library packages have been
>     mapped into corresponding `androidx.*` packages. For a full mapping of
>     all the old classes and build artifacts to the new ones, see the
>     [Package Refactoring](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/refactor) page.

So in simple words it is new library that you should use instead of support library as it have latest components and features.

Thus, your `PreferenceScreen` is same as `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen` but bundled with different wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So we can say that, in my example, writing `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen` instead of `PreferenceScreen` only is redundant since `androidx.preference.` is implicit?

Comment: I can see only one import in your project. but it would be good practice to import particular class whenever possible.

Comment: @tynn: is there any specific difference in this case because when me migrated one of our app other features seemed to be just changed from support to andoridx bundle. please add if I am missing something.

Comment: @KaranMer you mean, instead of having `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'` in build.grade, I should have, inside `SettingsFragment.java`: `import 'androidx.preference. ...`?

Comment: I meant the fact that AndroidX supports the _support fragments_ while the platform only supports the now deprecated platform fragments.

Comment: @Karan Mer "I can see only one import in your project. but it would be good practice to import particular class whenever possible." Could you please explain what you meant here, sir?

Comment: Beware, there may be a myriad of issues to debug if you use support frameworks alongside androidX frameworks in the same project.  For sanity's sake, it's wise to pick one or the other and stick with it for all imports.